# is there a way to create condition listener

Tags: android, listener

is there a way to create a listener that activates an event under a certain condition(boolean)?

i tried reading about creating custom listeners using interfaces but i dont think it's the answer for my question.

right now in my app i write an if statement everywhere so if i could just create a listener for it, it would be much easier.

```
set_A==B_Listener(????? {//listener takes place if a==b
        @Override
        public boolean event(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
             //do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: What if you just check for the condition inside your listener and execute the required code only when the condition is met ?

Comment: that's what i'm doing now but i tried to find a more efficient way

Answer (score 0):

Create a class variable for your statement, than you can attach an OnChangeListener to your statement in the onCreate method of your Activity

```
public class DummyActivity extends Activity {


interface OnStateChangeListener{

    public void onAttach(Activity activity);
    public void onStateChange(boolean state);
}

private boolean state;
private OnStateChangeListener listener;
private YourClass stateChangedCallback;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    listener = new OnStateChangeListener() {

        private Activity currentActivity;

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            currentActivity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStateChange(boolean state) {
            if (((DummyActivity) this.currentActivity).state != state) {
                stateChangedCallback.doSomething();
                ((DummyActivity) this.currentActivity).state = state;
            }
        }
    };
}



private void yourFunction() {
    boolean state = true;
    listener.onStateChange(state);

}
```

}

Comment: nickolaus can you please detail your example with what each part is responsible for? to be more specific - i didn't understand where do i specify the condition i want to meet